# Objective-C: object as parameter and returning object in a function

Tags: objective-c

This may be trivial.  I'm wondering if you can pass an object as parameter to a function, then function can operate on the object and then return the same object back.  I've got a work around for this, but would like to know if there  is a way to do it.

An Example:

```
-(objectA *)aFunctionWithParameter:(objectA *)param
{
    //...Operate on param

    return param;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Did something not work? Workaround??

Comment: Yes. You can. Works fine.   What is going awry?

Comment: Euh, what exactly is wrong with the current code?

Comment: Should work just fine.  Of course, returning the object is unnecessary, since the caller still (presumably) has the original object (which you have presumably modified in your method).

Comment: (It should be noted that this is no different from C, C++, Java, and a dozen other languages.)

Comment: Maybe he literally means a function, and not a method.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri - If he knew enough to be that precise in terminology he wouldn't need to ask the question.

Comment: I've tried using it as such: param = [self aFunctionWithParameter:param]; and got an error telling me that I no longer own the object when I tried to [param release];  Which tells me that I may have done something horrible. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it.
In objective-C, the pointers are passed by reference. So, when you change any fileds of an object received as a parameter of your function, you are modifying the actual object. On returning it, you will have updated object.

Comment: No, in Objective-C *objects* are passed by reference. The pointers themselves are passed by value, and they *are* the references to the objects being passed.

Comment: @Caleb So, if operation is performed on param, after the method existed, can I see the update on param?  Of course, I can try it myself and see!

Comment: @Hamid `param` has type `objectA*`, that is, it's a pointer to an instance of class objectA. The *pointer* is passed by value, which is another way to say that the *object* is passed by reference (because `param` is a reference to the object). If the function uses `param` to access the object, any changes it makes will of course persist after the function exits. If the function changes the pointer `param` itself, e.g. making it point to some other object, that change will not persist after the function exits.

Comment: @Caleb Ok, that is a great point.  So lets say I pass in NSBezierPath *path as parameter. within the function then I add to path, how can I ensure that the additions stay around until after function exits?

Comment: Well, again, since you're passing a *pointer to* to the object and not the object itself, any changes you make to the object will persist.